# I just want to retrieve database file data in android recycler view

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite, android-sqlite

All code is working good, but database can't create when i click on button.

I already created "morning_evening_supplications_data.db" file and paste into `android > src > main > assest` directory.

now i just to read out that database file, don't want to insert, update or delete data from this file.

please help me out. here are code of `DatabaseHelper.java` class.

```java
package com.example.me_azkar;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

import androidx.annotation.Nullable;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import static android.content.Context.MODE_PRIVATE;

public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    String data = MainActivity.getSupplication();

    // declare varible and store database basic information
    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "morning_evening_supplications_data.db";

    public static final String SUPPLICATION_TABLE_NAME = "supplication_detail";
    public static final String SUPPLICATION_MORNING_EVENING_TABLE_NAME = "supplication_morning_evening";
    public static final String SUPPLICATION_REFERENCE_TABLE_NAME = "supplication_reference";

    // SUPPLICATION TABLE COLUMNS NAMES
    public static final String SUPPLIICATION_COLUMN_0 = "supplication_id";
    public static final String SUPPLIICATION_COLUMN_1 = "supplication_repeat_no";
    public static final String SUPPLIICATION_COLUMN_2 = "supplication_important_info";
    public static final String SUPPLIICATION_COLUMN_3 = "supplication";
    public static final String SUPPLIICATION_COLUMN_4 = "supplication_urdu_translation";
    public static final String SUPPLIICATION_COLUMN_5 = "supplication_english_translation";
    public static final String SUPPLIICATION_COLUMN_6 = "supplication_detail";
    public static final String SUPPLIICATION_COLUMN_7 = "supplication_.commorning_evening_id";
    public static final String SUPPLIICATION_COLUMN_8 = "supplication_reference_id";

    // SUPPLICATION MORNING EVENING TABLE COLUMNS NAMES
    public static final String SUPPLICATION_MORNING_EVENING_COLUMN_0 = "supplication_morning_evening_id";
    public static final String SUPPLICATION_MORNING_EVENING_COLUMN_1 = "supplication_morning";
    public static final String SUPPLICATION_MORNING_EVENING_COLUMN_2 = "supplication_evening";
    public static final String SUPPLICATION_MORNING_EVENING_COLUMN_3 = "supplication_id";


    // SUPPLICATION REFERENCE TABLE COLUMNS NAMES
    public static final String SUPPLICATION_REFERENCE_COLUMN_0 = "supplication_reference_id";
    public static final String SUPPLICATION_REFERENCE_COLUMN_1 = "supplication_book_name_1";
    public static final String SUPPLICATION_REFERENCE_COLUMN_2 = "supplication_hadith_no_1";
    public static final String SUPPLICATION_REFERENCE_COLUMN_3 = "supplication_book_name_2";
    public static final String SUPPLICATION_REFERENCE_COLUMN_4 = "supplication_hadith_no_2";
    public static final String SUPPLICATION_REFERENCE_COLUMN_5 = "supplication_id";

    // constructor
    public DatabaseHelper(@Nullable Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    }

    public ArrayList<Model> getRowData() {
        ArrayList<Model> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT sd.supplication_id, sd.supplication_repeat_no, sd.supplication_important_info, sd.supplication, sd.supplication_urdu_translation, sd.supplication_english_translation, sd.supplication_detail, sr.supplication_book_name_1 || \"، \" || sr.supplication_hadith_no_1 AS supplication_references FROM supplication_detail AS sd \n" +
                "JOIN supplication_morning_evening AS sme \n" +
                "ON sd.supplication_morning_evening_id = sme.supplication_morning_evening_id\n" +
                "JOIN supplication_reference as sr\n" +
                "ON sd.supplication_reference_id = sr.supplication_reference_id\n" +
                "WHERE sme." +data+ " = 1", null);

        if(cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                Model model = new Model();
                model.setSupplication_id(cursor.getString(0));
                model.setSupplication_repeat(cursor.getString(1));
                model.setSupplication_important_info(cursor.getString(2));
                model.setSupplication(cursor.getString(3));
                model.setSupplication_urdu_translation(cursor.getString(4));
                model.setSupplication_english_translation(cursor.getString(5));
                model.setSupplication_detail(cursor.getString(6));
                model.setSupplication_reference_no(cursor.getString(7));
                arrayList.add(model);
            }while(cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        return arrayList;
    }
}
```

here are some images of my application when ii debug

1. Database Inspector
   [Database Inspector Screenshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ucOc.png)

> Original Database file is `48kb` and generated database file is `12kb`

1. `Package Name > Data > Data > Databases`
   [Database Data Package Screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D0xK8.png)